# 2nd UICollectionView inside UIScrollview not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I Have

> -> MainScrollView
>   (. Labels
>        ....
>   . 1st CollectionView
>   . Labels
>   . WebView
>   . 2nd CollectionView )

Im trying to add labels and WebView programmatically whereas the scrollview and collectionViews are designed in storyboard.

The scroll, 1st CollectionView, WebViews are working fine, when i use to add the 2nd collectionView the WebView is not working and also, the 2nd collectionView is not scrolling and also its delegate methods are not being called

I referred these links too, but they wont help my issue
1. [UICollectionView inside UIScrollView not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634939/uicollectionview-inside-uiscrollview-not-scrolling)
2. [UICollectionView inside UICollectionView will not scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134244/uicollectionview-inside-uicollectionview-will-not-scroll)

I am not sure why it is being affected, Suggest me any ideas to fix and do this task

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: It's not good to add any Scrollview and its sub classes like CollectionView, TableView into another Scrollview. Maybe you had a bad design, please consider to change the design.

Comment: @YunCHEN, Please have a look at my edit

Comment: @Lalitkumar i added my ViewController to a link to refer code https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2JNfyRRcL0GSTgyTXoxdTU4dEk

Comment: also the screen shot of mainscrollview utilities https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2JNfyRRcL0GaDVsdDJPdVRnRzA and the 2nd collectionView's https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2JNfyRRcL0GVDBESnJSNnRfX3c